# Why do i get a list index out of range error with entries with a length of four digits?

Tags: python, algorithm, indexing

I wrote this algorithm that returns the shortest sequence using operations to sort a list of numbers.
is sorted by always reversing the order of the first n elements of the list and removing the first element from the list.

```
def wenden(arr, n):
    #dreht die Ersten n elemente um
    i = 0
    while i < n // 2:
        arr[i], arr[n - i-1] = arr[n - i-1], arr[i]
        i += 1
    arr.pop(0)
    return arr

def ist_Sortirt(arr):
    for i in range(len(arr) - 1):
        if arr[i] > arr[i+1]:
            return False
    return True

def best_sort(arr):
    flips = []
    if not ist_Sortirt(arr):
        for i in range(1, len(arr)-1):
            sort_lis = wenden(arr, i + 1)
            flipi = [i+1]
            flipi.append(best_sort(sort_lis))
            flips.append(flipi)
        ret = 0
        for i in range(1, len(flips)-1):
            if len(flips[i]) < len(flips[ret]):
                ret = i
        return flips[ret]
    else:
        return []
```

I have tested the script with different input lists, a list with the phrases should be output, but I always get a list index out of range error at `return flips[ret]` in `best_sort()` if the input is longer than 3 numbers

input: [2,1,3,6]

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\programming\Aufgabe3a.py", line 69, in <module>
    print(best_sort(pfannkuchen))
  File "D:\programming\Aufgabe3a.py", line 47, in best_sort
    flipi.append(best_sort(sort_lis))
  File "D:\programming\Aufgabe3a.py", line 53, in best_sort
    return flips[ret]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Include the input sample and the actual traceback error.

Comment: I think you are using a deep copy of the input array in the best_sort() function because you are modifying the input array with wenden() which can lead to unexpected behavior.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is an exponential function, `O(c^n)`. Have you tried using this on a list of size 20?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue.
Try it now.

Change the loop range in best_sort instead of looping from 1 to len(arr) - 1, you should loop from 0 to len(arr) to avoid index out of range errors.

```
def wenden(arr, n):
    i = 0
    while i < n // 2:
        arr[i], arr[n - i - 1] = arr[n - i - 1], arr[i]
        i += 1
    arr.pop(0)
    return arr

def ist_Sortirt(arr):
    for i in range(len(arr) - 1):
        if arr[i] > arr[i + 1]:
            return False
    return True

def best_sort(arr):
    if len(arr) <= 1:
        return []

    flips = []

    if not ist_Sortirt(arr):
        for i in range(len(arr)):
            sort_lis = copy.deepcopy(arr)
            sort_lis = wenden(sort_lis, i + 1)
            flipi = [i + 1]
            flipi.append(best_sort(sort_lis))
            flips.append(flipi)

        ret = 0
        for i in range(1, len(flips)):
            if len(flips[i]) < len(flips[ret]):
                ret = i
        return flips[ret]
    else:
        return []
```

Comment: You could include a minimal explanation of what was wrong with OP's implementation and what is the approach used in your solution.

Comment: I explained it in the comment to him below his question before I post it in my answer. I can provide it here as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
def best_sort(arr):
    flips = []
    if not ist_Sortirt(arr):
        for i in range(1, len(arr)-1):
            sort_lis = wenden(arr, i + 1)
            flipi = [i+1]
            flipi.append(best_sort(sort_lis))
            flips.append(flipi)
        ret = 0
        for i in range(1, len(flips)-1):
            if len(flips[i]) < len(flips[ret]):
                ret = i
        return flips[ret]
```

Eventually, the code reaches a point where `arr` only has two elements.

So the loop `for i in range(1, len(arr)-1)` becomes `for i in range(1, 1)` and
does not execute at all, therefore no items are appended to `flips`, and therefore `flips[ret]` is out of range.